# excel formula in one column based on variable entries in another column

Tags: excel, excel-2010

My goal is to populate column G for each row with a CPTCode(column B).  If I were to copy and paste by hand this would simply be: f2/f5, f3/f5,f4/f5,f6/f15,f7/f15, etc.  Column A contains the names of staff.  Each month staff codes for different types of procedures(columns B and C) and a variable quantity of each(column E).  The rows with total in column B represent the end of a staff person's monthly list of codes.  We are hoping to provide monthly updates to our service chiefs.  I am hoping someone might be able to help me devise a formula I could use to copy down column G.  We are looking at roughly 3000-4000 rows of code per month for about 200 different clinical providers.

CPTCode CPTName Work RVU    FY16 Total Qty  FY16 Total RVU  CPT's % of FY RVUs
96119   NEUROPSYCH TESTING BY TECH  0.6 76  41.8
99212   OFFICE/OUTPATIENT VISIT EST 0.5 2   1.0 
T1016   CASE MANAGEMENT 0.5 1   0.5 
Total           79  43.3
H0038   SELF-HELP/PEER SVC PER 15MIN    0.0 727 0.0 
90853   GROUP PSYCHOTHERAPY 0.6 236 139.2
99212   OFFICE/OUTPATIENT VISIT EST 0.5 153 73.4
S9446   PT EDUCATION NOC GROUP  0.4 105 42.0
99211   OFFICE/OUTPATIENT VISIT EST 0.2 44  7.9 
90785   PSYTX COMPLEX INTERACTIVE   0.3 10  3.3 
99202   OFFICE/OUTPATIENT VISIT NEW 0.9 1   0.9 
99213   OFFICE/OUTPATIENT VISIT EST 1.0 1   1.0 
H0031   MH HEALTH ASSESS BY NON-MD  0.6 1   0.6 
Total           1278    268.4
H0038   SELF-HELP/PEER SVC PER 15MIN    0.0 452 0.0 
98967   HC PRO PHONE CALL 11-20 MIN 0.5 1   0.5 
Total           453 0.5

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dw44F.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPs2j.jpg)

Comment: A small example of your data and what you expect would be helpful.  Create them in excel then copy and paste the values here.  If you cannot format them correctly leave the values and someone will help format it properly.  Do this in your original post not the comments.

Comment: Please provide more detail on what you have tried so far. The information you have provided in your question is unclear, provide example data for each column and the expected result from that data.